# In Postresql. How to replicate rows based on the number value in a column

Tags: postgresql

**Here is problem below:**

```
Name    Start Time  End Time    Number
A1      5:13 PM     5:43 PM     0
A2      7:06 PM     8:51 PM     2
A3      6:36 PM     8:06 PM     3
A4      4:51 PM     7:51 PM     4
```

I would like to replicate rows based on Number values and include three new Columns (New_Start_Time, New_End_Time, and Minutes) I'm new to Sql, how I can do this in Postresql?

**I expected the result below:**

```
Name    Start Time  End Time    Number  New_Start_Time  New_End_Time
A1      5:13 PM     5:43 PM     0       5:13 PM         5:43 PM
A2      7:06 PM     8:51 PM     2       7:06 PM         8:00 PM
A2      7:06 PM     8:51 PM     2       8:00 PM         8:51 PM
A3      6:36 PM     8:06 PM     3       6:36 PM         7:00 PM
A3      6:36 PM     8:06 PM     3       7:00 PM         8:00 PM
A3      6:36 PM     8:06 PM     3       8:00 PM         8:06 PM
A4      4:51 PM     7:51 PM     4       4:51 PM         5:00 PM
A4      4:51 PM     7:51 PM     4       5:00 PM         6:00 PM
A4      4:51 PM     7:51 PM     4       6:00 PM         7:00 PM
A4      4:51 PM     7:51 PM     4       7:00 PM         7:51 PM
```

Comment: Based in this logic you don't even need the number column. Because the number is defined by the difference in ours between start and end which is more accurate. The reason I mentioning it is what would/should happen if you have this case: `A5      4:51PM   5:51PM     4` ?

Comment: You are corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `generate_series()` and calculating the number of hours between start and end time.

So we need to first calculate the "base start time" by rounding the `start_time` to the full hour. This is also used to add the hours when duplicating the rows:

```
with rounded as (
  select name, 
         start_time,
         end_time, 
         date_trunc('hour', start_time)::time as base_start_time,
         extract(hour from (date_trunc('hour', end_time) + interval '1 hour') - date_trunc('hour', start_time))::int as num_hours
  from times
)
select name,
       start_time, 
       end_time, 
       case 
         when h = 1 then start_time
         else base_start_time + interval '1 hour' * (h - 1)
       end as new_start_time,
       case
          when h = num_hours then end_time
          else base_start_time + interval '1 hour' * h
       end as new_end_time
from rounded
  cross join generate_series(1, num_hours, 1) as t(h)  
order by name, new_start_time;
```

The [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) is used to calculate the base offset and the number of hours that need to be generated. If you are sure you can trust your `number` column, you can replace the `extract(hour ...) as num_hours` expression with just `number as num_hours`.

The new start and new end is then calculated based on which "hour" the row reflects. For the first hour we use the existing start time, for all others we just add the number of hours needed. For the new end time we need to check if it's the last hour.

The above returns:

```
name | start_time | end_time | new_start_time | new_end_time
-----+------------+----------+----------------+-------------
A1   | 17:13      | 17:43    | 17:13          | 17:43       
A2   | 19:06      | 20:51    | 19:06          | 20:00       
A2   | 19:06      | 20:51    | 20:00          | 20:51       
A3   | 18:36      | 20:06    | 18:36          | 19:00       
A3   | 18:36      | 20:06    | 19:00          | 20:00       
A3   | 18:36      | 20:06    | 20:00          | 20:06       
A4   | 16:51      | 19:51    | 16:51          | 17:00       
A4   | 16:51      | 19:51    | 17:00          | 18:00       
A4   | 16:51      | 19:51    | 18:00          | 19:00       
A4   | 16:51      | 19:51    | 19:00          | 19:51
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GAZP30312